# Best ways to improve this question?

Tags: support, edits, specific-question

I tried to explain myself and edited this question but I noticed someone just recently downvoted it still anyways:
[how to edit html using the webbrowser control? (turn on WYSIWYG features)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13768310/how-to-using-editing-on-webbrowser-control-turn-on-wysiwyg-features)

I wonder if anyone has any ideas for improvement to get it upvoted again or at least get even on helpful. I wish someone could flag a question first for editing and if it does not seem right after editing then close it (if its a good question I will definitely re-edit and sometimes even add references to wikis or articles to explain what Iam trying to do better also).

Getting back to the question it was about if the web browser control had WYSIWYG controls or editing features that could be turned on. How could I edit the question to make it sound better or did I just receive some harsh critics?

Comment: This is what "on hold" is - a way of indicating that a question needs to be edited. It can be re-opened afterwards. If after 5 (or 7, I am not clear and it might have changed) days, it has not been edited into shape, it is closed. So what you want is what you have already.

Comment: I went ahead and tried adding code for the question above to update it. I hope someone can edit the code if its too much and remove irrelevant parts. But the problem is that sometimes if you show 10 lines of code you have no choice but to link to the code because it takes more then that to answer the question. Anyone know of any good vb.net or c# code viewer websites? My main concern is right now Iam doing a project in unmanaged code (c/c++) which is almost mission impossible to answer without link to main source sometimes. yucky? yes! So I want to improve that post first.

Comment: Please DO NOT edit the answer into the question. Let the question be a question. Flag your deleted answer to be undeleted and fix it up so that it is truly an answer to the question. Right now what you have is a hot mess.

Comment: I am still working on it but have updated as you said kate. Hope I can learn from this as I post in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the comments, some people had trouble understanding the request. Elaboration on the phrase "similar to edit html" would be helpful, since that is the core of what you hope to accomplish.

More importantly, your question appears to be a request for a tutorial or broad help. Good Stack Overflow questions usually focus on specific problems that can be answered succinctly.

Instead of asking "How can I do X?" consider trying a few things. Then you can ask a question that says "I tried this (see my code) and it didn't work because..." This shows that you made an attempt, and allows answerers to point out specific areas in which your code which can be corrected to accomplish the desired goal.

Try to include a trimmed-down version of the code that produces the problem as an example so that answerers can experience the issue themselves. In addition to the code you post in the question, you can use [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) or other appropriate site to create a live demonstration.

Comment: Just make sure your key code is included in the question and not only in the jsFiddle.  :)

Comment: @Joe Thanks. I've added clarification on that point.

Comment: I changed that one section at the top you were referring to. I can look up that code if I can find out where I put it to show how I solved the question if you think that would help.

Comment: I was helping someone with a personal project and I wanted to use that code in a project of my own (no copyright - open source and the original owner gave me permission to)  but the main section to post it would be more then 10 lines because the code is weirdly formatted and references other variables or objects. If you think that would improve it I could do post it but I think people would get it confused with another question

Comment: Too much code is almost as bad as too little; many people will not have time to read it to figure out the problem. Instead, you will need to find a way to narrow down the problem to a specific element of the code, and just post that part. For help on doing that, see the "Tricks for Trimming" section of [sscce.org](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Its really hard to be effective sometimes with the code Iam using. I can try and post the relevant lines that solved the question to improve its readability if you think it would help.

Comment: I cannot get away with more then 10-20 lines here which is impossible to answer some of my questions with see my dilemma? I can post a relevant link of a discussion I started with the other person on msdn forums but I hope not to have a redundant link session going.

Comment: I wish I could mark you both as answers but you elaborated on some things thanks for helping.

Answer (score 3):

You actually have a great clue in the closing reason

The question is unclear and the English is hard to understand. You can ask in a comment for editing help from native English speakers.

Furthermore the question doesn't seem thought out, there's no code which is frowned upon on SO and it seems to me that if you'd try and research a little you wouldn't have to ask this question at all.

My edit would include my attempt at a solution and some background regarding why I am stuck exactly.

You could consider adding a comment such as:

> An edit by a native English speaker will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Thanks I edited it but if it still needs improvement I hope someone can step in. I normally do include code (at least on msdn forums) and reference msdn documentation if necessary. Sometimes confusion abounds and I am not for sure which documentation to reference. It gets difficult on here as all my questions might need some editing at some point when documentation is found from msdn or elewhere to reference to not confuse people.